# Need Datatable Data to be accessed across threads

Tags: c#, .net

I am currently developing a client-server application in C#. Now at my client side, i have a thread that is continuously listening for responses from server, which in this case is data. This data is stored in a datatable. Now i have another thread that has to access this datatable with stored data from the server and perform some computations. Now i'm using a delegate to set the datatable for computations but i get an Exception "Collection has been modified. The enumeration operation may not execute." at the computing function. I have used flags so as to set the table only when the particular computing method has finished computing, so as to avoid the exception but to no use. How else can i implement the above requirement?Any assistance would be appreciated,
Thanks in advance.

```
There is one method here executing continuously Which is Listening for server response say MethodListen:
MethodListen()
{
//Listen To Server
//Get Data sent from server into a temp table
if(flag=true)
{
//Use a delegate to set the MainTable
}
}
Other Method which uses MainTable To execute is executing on a separate thread
MethodCompute()
{
flag=false;
for(//conditions)
{
   //table is accessed
}
flag=true;
}
This is the delegate used to set the table:
delegate void SetTableCallback(DataTable dt);    //this is used to remove cross thread exception
private void SetTable(DataTable dt_header)
{
        try
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetTableCallback d = new SetTableCallback(SetTable);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { dt_header });
            }
            else
            {
                consolidated_copy.Clear();
                for (int c = 0; c < dt_header.Rows.Count; c++)
                {
                    consolidated_copy.ImportRow(dt_header.Rows[c]);
                }
                consolidated_copy.AcceptChanges();
            }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    //Handle
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you have some code you can share with us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally Figured out a solution. Instead of using A datatable I used a ConcurrentDictionary instead to allow concurrent access across threads, since I know that at any point only upto two threads will be accessing my dictionary. I  have added the links i referred to here for reference. Thanks for your answers everybody!

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/

Answer (score 0):

`IEnumerable` hesitates to operate on modified collection. Because internally version is is maintained, whenever list is modified, version is incremented and error and compared and error is thrown. And your resource in this case datatable must be accessed by only single thread at any point of time in order to give the `IEnumerable` non modified collection,so that it (`foreach` basically) can operate efficiently .

Now to resolve your issue it is basically a **thread synchronous issue** as you are not providing the code, my guess is. Now you can avoid or resolve the thread synchronization issue by using lock, mutex etc.

Have a look at this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/threading/thread-synchronization

Comment: I have tried using a Lock, but that didn't help. I came across an article that said locks only help with locking updations to a particular row, Say if another thread is updating Row 2, locks will prevent other threads from accessing Row 2, Do correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Yes. But why do you want to update and access the row 2 at the same clock tick? What's the necessary

Comment: Because, One thread is clearing and creating rows, at the same time there is another thread computing with the same data, Problem is i think the same copy is being accessed at both ends because of the SetTable Delegate, which is exactly what i want to avoid hence i used the delegate.

Comment: So let first thread compute data, another thread sleep till data is computed or vice versa. Synchronize the two so that each won't fight to access the resource one after the other

Comment: Isn't there an alternate approach, such that my listening thread continuously gets data and stores into one datatable, and my compute thread at every tick accesses the data to compute? Apart from using Thread.Sleep?

Comment: Tasks from parallel library  I am not sure on this. Give a try.

Comment: Thanks,Will try it out.

Comment: @ShrinidhiNarasimhan  Check out this http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.in/2016/11/c-wait-for-thread-to-finish-without.html

Comment: Hey, I tried using Thread.Join,It didn't work as expected,Im executing both threads in a continuous while loop,